# Problem mixer.music.get_pos() after set position by mixer.music.set_pos()

Tags: python, pygame, pygame-mixer

I use the `pygame.mixer` module for my music player
While doing the project, I came across a problem that I realized was from the `pygame.mixer` module
When I set the new position inside the `set_pos()` function
`get_pos()` function does not output the new position and outputs the initial position

```
from time import sleep
from pygame import mixer

mixer.init()
mixer.music.load("file.mp3")
mixer.music.play()
mixer.music.set_pos(10.0)
sleep(2)
print(mixer.music.get_pos())
```

output:

```
2000 ms
```

If for my logic this output is correct:

```
12000 ms
```

Comment: See [`pygame.mixer.music.set_pos()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/music.html#pygame.mixer.music.set_pos): *"This sets the position in the music file where playback will start. **The meaning of "pos", a float (or a number that can be converted to a float), depends on the music format.**"*. So the unity of the argument is definitely not seconds.

Answer (score 0):

- According to the [docs](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/music.html#pygame.mixer.music.set_pos) for `set_pos()`:

> This sets the position in the music file where playback will start. The meaning of "pos", a float (or a number that can be converted to a float), depends on the music format.
>
> For MOD files, pos is the integer pattern number in the module. For OGG it is the absolute position, in seconds, from the beginning of the sound. For MP3 files, it is the relative position, in seconds, from the current position. For absolute positioning in an MP3 file, first call rewind().

So, you *could* use this code:

```py
def set_pos(s): # /!\ seconds
    pygame.mixer.music.rewind() # mp3 files need a rewind first
    freq = pygame.mixer.get_init()[0] # get the music frequency
    pygame.mixer.music.set_pos(int(s*freq))
```

However, using `set_pos()` can give you errors like this, for example with `.ogg` sound files:

```
pygame.error: set_pos unsupported for this codec
```

---

You should then prefer using [`pygame.mixer.music.play(loops, start)`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/music.html#pygame.mixer.music.play) like this:

```py
pygame.mixer.music.play(0, s) # /!\ seconds
```

From the docs:

> The starting position depends on the format of the music played. MP3 and OGG use the position as time in seconds. For MP3 files the start time position selected may not be accurate as things like variable bit rate encoding and ID3 tags can throw off the timing calculations. For MOD music it is the pattern order number. Passing a start position will raise a NotImplementedError if the start position cannot be set.

As a general rule, you should be using `.ogg` files since over `.mp3` since they had been implemented before and they have a move precise positioning ("*For MP3 files the start time position selected may not be accurate*").

- `get_pos()` can give you weird results, as it only shows for how long the music has **been playing**. So, it does not take into account the fact that you "jump" a full minute if the music started playing 1 second ago. It will output you `1000` (ms). Docs:

> This gets the number of milliseconds that the music has been playing for. The returned time only represents how long the music has been playing; it does not take into account any starting position offsets.

---

Linked: [pygame.error: set_pos unsupported for this codec](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44133774)